# How to add space between inline-block elements?

Tags: html, css

To be clear, I do not want to **remove** space between inline-block elements - I want to **add** it.

What I want is to have a grid of menu items that could have 2, 3 or 4 items to a line, which I'd like to achieve using media queries.

How can I add space between my li items, but also have **no margin on the left and right sides of each row**? (Padding will not fix this.) Can I achieve this using only CSS?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#main {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
.item img {
  width: 200px;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <li class="item clearfix">
    <a href="project.html">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/06/23/business/greece-portraits-restauranteur/greece-portraits-restauranteur-mediumThreeByTwo225.jpg" alt="Portraits From Greece as It Endures a Crisis">
    </a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="item clearfix">
    <a href="project.html">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/06/23/business/greece-portraits-restauranteur/greece-portraits-restauranteur-mediumThreeByTwo225.jpg" alt="Portraits From Greece as It Endures a Crisis">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

</div>
```

Comment: The HTML is not valid li must be directly under ul or ol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
<html><head>
<style>
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#main {
  max-width: 452px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
.item1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding:0px 4px;
}
.item img {
  width: 200px;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="main">

 <li class="item clearfix">
    <a href="project.html">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/06/23/business/greece-portraits-restauranteur/greece-portraits-restauranteur-mediumThreeByTwo225.jpg" alt="Portraits From Greece as It Endures a Crisis">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item1 clearfix">
    <a href="project.html">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/06/23/business/greece-portraits-restauranteur/greece-portraits-restauranteur-mediumThreeByTwo225.jpg" alt="Portraits From Greece as It Endures a Crisis">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item clearfix">
    <a href="project.html">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/06/23/business/greece-portraits-restauranteur/greece-portraits-restauranteur-mediumThreeByTwo225.jpg" alt="Portraits From Greece as It Endures a Crisis">
      </div>
     </a>
  </li>

 </div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the padding:

```
.item{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I want no space - margin or padding where my li items meet the parent div. I want the edges to sit against the div.

Comment: You have to comment out space between </li> and next <li> or just right then in one line. Inline elements sees the carriage return as 3px margin (do not know why).
You can just do it like this:
    </li><!--
--><li>