# How do I give spacing/padding between my divs

Tags: html, css

I have 3 input box and I want to give padding between them.
I can't understand where to put padding.
[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/saadtufail/pen/GLzgwj)

I have 3 Input boxes.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
body {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background: #313E50;
}

.text-input {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-input input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

.text-input input[type="text"]+label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #E03616;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.text-input input[type="text"]:focus+label {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-120%) translateX(0%);
  transform: translateY(-120%) translateX(0%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

.text-input input[type="text"]:focus {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-input">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Try typing something in here!">
  <label for="input1">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="text-input">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Try typing something in here!">
  <label for="input1">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="text-input">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Try typing something in here!">
  <label for="input1">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;` makes zero sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562815/how-to-add-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 4):

Add `margin-right` on `.text-input`

```
.text-input{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;/*Add This*/
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GLzJvM

Comment: Answers which explain the difference in code are upvoted more often than those which merely say "try this" with code. It's not required, but answers without explanation are usually not as helpful as those with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**please try this css :**

```
.text-input {
  margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: is the left really necessary?

Comment: @Sam left and right margin will be responsive version useful.

Comment: Answers which explain the difference in code are upvoted more often than those which merely say "try this" with code. It's not required, but answers without explanation are usually not as helpful as those with explanation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey only margins are required. so, no need to explanation

Comment: So should the OP remove all of the other CSS? Add these to existing properties? The answer to the comment by Sam could also be integrated.